# A link in the top bar to site analytics

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-bar, site-analytics

I just gained the [25k privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) and from reading the Help Center page I was wondering where the link to the [`/site-analytics`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) would be...?

Turns out there isn't a link in the top bar like for the other privileges (e.g: review queues, moderator tools)... This hits me as frustrating, I've always enjoyed the way all the functionalities **integrate nicely into the UI**. But now, for the last privilege, I have to navigate to the Help Center page to find the link or write an URL... This clicking away from the top bar, away from the user profile, away from all the things that make my experience an immersion, is just a anticlimactic.

Could we have better integration of the 25k privilege? And where would be the optimal place to put that hypothetical link?

[image: top-bar link icons]

Comment: The site analytics are largely useless. I suspect that most people visit them a couple/few times after they get the privilege and then almost never again. The rest of the links in the topbar, mostly, go to useful things that at least a reasonable number of people use daily. Personally, I'd really prefer to **not** have a link to the site analytics cluttering up the topbar UI.

Comment: @Makyen consider converting your comment to an answer, I had thought about the points you raise but... I'd still like a link. I was also amazed no one had asked for this before, so it's a worthy FR, FTR...

Comment: I don't think that would be a good answer, because it's an opinion about the use of the tool (and a potential link), not really about a link to the tool.